# Как запретить доступ на просмотр файла, но разрешить его выполнение?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, безопасность

Есть js файл (main) который с помощью модуля подключает в себя другой js файл (second).

```
import {second} from './second.js';

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    second();
});
```

Со своего сайта я предоставляю людям ссылку на файл main.js чтобы они могли запустить код который находится в second.js `http://domain/main.js` и важно чтобы пользователи могли увидеть только тот код который находится в файле main.js и ограничить доступ к second.js. На данный момент я могу зайти по адресу `http://domain/second.js` и прочитать всё содержимое. Как мне выполнять second.js но весь код скрыть от людей?)

Comment: кому надо все равно найдет этот код. чего вы там прятать собрались?

Comment: просто не добавляйте код и его никто не увидит (можно использовать обфускатор, но это не скрытие файлов, подорбнее почитайте в интернете)